# How do I remove factor variables from my regression coefficients plot with plot_summs & plot_coefs?

Tags: r, regression

I am using `plot_summs()` and `plot_coefs()` from the `jtools` package to plot my regression coefficients.

However, I want to remove some coefficients from my plot but when I do this:

```
plot_coefs(mod1,
           omit.coefs = c("(Intercept)", "Maritalstatus", "numberofkids",
                          "age2", "education"))
```

it only removed numeric variables such as age2 and numberofkids, but it doesn't remove the others (factors variables). Why?

Answer (score 0):

It's a variable name conflict in a function called `make_tidies`, specific to `jtools`.

Let's do a reproducible example first.

This gives us a small data frame with your variables, N = 20.

```
df <- data.frame(numberofkids = sample(c(0,1,2), 20, replace = T),
             education = factor(sample(c("HS","C","G"), 20, replace = T)),
             age2 = runif(20,20,60),
             LastVariableStanding <- rnorm(20),
             Maritalstatus = factor(sample(c("S","M","D"), 20, replace = T)),
             outcome <- runif(20,0,1))

names(df) <- c("numberofkids","education","age2","LastVariableStanding","Maritalstatus", "outcome")

mod1 <- lm(outcome ~ Maritalstatus + education + age2 + 
                               LastVariableStanding + numberofkids, data = df)
```

So if we fit `mod1`, and then use

```
plot_coefs(mod1, omit.coefs = c("(Intercept)", "Maritalstatus", 
                               "numberofkids", "age2", "education")),
```

we should get a regression on `LastVariableStanding` exclusively.

Instead, I get this:

[image: plot_coefs but with factor level variables too]

just as you describe.

The function `make_tidies()` is called within `plot_coefs`. It does a lot of work to extract the parameters from the regression model such that it can pass the values back to `plot_coefs`.

Deep in the guts of `make_tidies()`, you will see a table like this:

```
    # A tibble: 8 × 8
  term                 estimate std.error statistic p.value conf.low conf.high model  
                                              
1 (Intercept)           0.971     0.282       3.45  0.00481   0.358    1.58    Model 1
2 MaritalstatusM       -0.0296    0.174      -0.170 0.868    -0.409    0.349   Model 1
3 MaritalstatusS       -0.0163    0.146      -0.111 0.913    -0.334    0.302   Model 1
4 educationG           -0.216     0.192      -1.12  0.283    -0.635    0.203   Model 1
5 educationHS          -0.123     0.185      -0.663 0.520    -0.527    0.281   Model 1
6 age2                 -0.00779   0.00565    -1.38  0.193    -0.0201   0.00452 Model 1
7 LastVariableStanding -0.0913    0.0684     -1.34  0.207    -0.240    0.0577  Model 1
8 numberofkids         -0.0954    0.106      -0.900 0.386    -0.326    0.136   Model 1
```

The check for omitting variables has a selection of

```
tidies$term %nin% omit.coefs
```

This will kick out the continuous variables because their names haven't changed, but will include the factor levels because their names have changed due to `lm` (I think).  Explicitly, `Maritalstatus != MaritalstatusS`, and so on.

Try using the `mod1` variable names instead of your data.frame column names in the `omit.coefs`.

```
plot_coefs(mod1, omit.coefs = c("(Intercept)", "MaritalstatusS", 
         "MaritalstatusM",  "numberofkids", "age2", "educationG", "educationHS"))
```

I get a graph for `LastVariableStanding`, which is I think you want.

[image: plot_coeff with the desired variable]